# Crash when I use CRibbonUI.InvalidateControl or CRibbonUI.Invalidate in office2007 but it was good in office2013

Tags: c++, com, office365, add-in

[image]

I'm trying to develop a Windows office plug-in int ppt. There's a login button there. Its initial state is not logged in. When I click on it, its status is changed to login, I need change the text above it, I query to update function is RibbonUI InvalidateControl or Invalidate, but when I call these functions, in the click event happened to crash. But it's well in office2013. Why?

```
STDMETHOD(UILoad)(IDispatch* ribbon) 
{
    m_ribbonUI = ribbon;
    //m_ribbonUI.InvalidateControl(_T("LoginButton"));
    return S_OK;
}
STDMETHODIMP CConnect::LoginButtonClicked( IDispatch* ribbon )
{
    CConnect::loginLable = CComBSTR(_T("Logged"));
    m_ribbonUI.InvalidateControl(_T("LoginButton"));
    return S_OK;
}
```

This is my project address：
https://github.com/Barmaco/NativeAddIn

Thanks!

Comment: "happened to crash" is not an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that a reference to the `ribbon` object interface is passed as a parameter to every related callback call. Hence caching a reference to the interface obtained during the call of `UILoad` may not be a good idea as the underlying object may be recreated due to later customization or optimization and the referenced one be no longer valid. So prefer using the `ribbon` interface passed as the function parameter.